# When do I need to mention the application class in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit

So my test class cannot find the beans if I do not mention the application test in the test class annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=[MySpringApplication::class])
@WebAppConfiguration
class MyFooIT{...}
```

I've seen (and written) other tests (in other projects and in this) where I did not need to mention the class explicitly.

I'm not sure *why* this is happening and I'm suspecting not knowing might result in my running into issues later on.

When do you need to provide a class with the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and when don't you?

Comment: Is the package of this integration test different from the package that MySpringApplication is in? This would happen when the spring classpath scanning logic cannot find the class automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are two situations when you may have to specify the application class you want to use in the `@SpringBootTest`:

1. When your test class is out of the root package of your application class (more details around the structure [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html))
2. When you have more than one application class under the package of your main application. This usually happens when you have dependencies using the same package (Module A use `com.example` as root package, and Module B depends on Module A and also use `com.example` as root package)

You may check if your `MyFooIT` is under the hierarchy of the root package (containing `MySpringApplication`), or if you have multiple application classes under the same root package.